# MK7 VW GTI (2015) unable to receive metadata over bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing, android-auto

When using Bluetooth audio in my mark7 VW GTI  with my Pixel 3 on Android 11 the GTI can no longer receive any metadata other than the track positon. On-screen and steering-wheel controls that used to work to skip, pause, play, etc. all are unresponsive. This started at some point a year ago probably after an Android system update. Unfortunately the car does not have built-in android auto integration. My wife's LGthinq 7 has no issues.

Multiple attempts at resetting the Bluetooth settings on my phone and the car and repairing have not fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling Developer Mode and setting the AVRCP version down to 1.3 (was at 1.5) corrected the issue. After doing so and resetting my phone the metadata displayed properly and I was able to use the car controller to control my playlist again.

> To enable developer options on the pixel 4a pull down notification shade and click on the gear to get to settings.
> Scroll down and choose About phone
> Scroll down to the bottom and click on Build number 7 or 8 times quickly until you see a message that says you are now a developer.
>
> To change AVRCP settings go back to settings and choose System.
> Scroll down to the bottom and choose Advanced then Developer Options
> Scroll about 1/2 way down in developer options and find Bluetooth AVRCP Version and change it to 1.3 then exit settings and reboot phone] [Source](https://www.vwvortex.com/threads/android-bluetooth-music-display-problem.7028124/page-2#post-114901135)

This worked for me and was such a pain to find I wanted to get it on SE for better visibility for anyone else googling the issue.